# How to set up SortBy columns in Dataset dynamically?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

Given a dataset like this:

```
ds = Dataset@{<|"C_1" -> 5, "C_2" -> 2, "C_3" -> 3|>, <|"C_1" -> 2, 
     "C_2" -> 3, "C_3" -> 4|>, <|"C_1" -> 3, "C_2" -> 2, 
     "C_3" -> 1|>, <|"C_1" -> 2, "C_2" -> 3, "C_3" -> 8|>};
```

Notice that there is `_` in column names occasionally.
I want to define a function to sort rows with columns set up dynamically to be used like this: `fDatasetSortBy["C_1","C_3","C_2"]` or `fDatasetSortBy["C_2","C_3","C_1"]`.

```
(*1st*) fDatasetSortBy[s1_, s2_, s3_] := ds[SortBy[{# s1,# s2, # s3}&]]
```

or

```
(*2nd*) fDatasetSortBy[s1_, s2_, s3_] := 
  ds[SortBy[ToExpression["{#" <> s1 <> ",#" <> s2 <> ", #" <> s3 <> "}&"]]]
```

but the `1st` case does not work, the `2nd` one comes up `Failure[...]` (`"MessageTemplate" :> Function::slota`) if there `_` exists in column names. How to make a pefect one? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fDatasetSortBy]
fDatasetSortBy[s1_, s2_, s3_] := ds[SortBy[{#[s1] &, #[s2] &, #[s3] &}]]
```

Examples:

```
fDatasetSortBy["C_1", "C_3", "C_2"]
```

[image]

```
fDatasetSortBy["C_2", "C_3", "C_1"]
```

[image]

Note: you can also use `ds[SortBy[{Slot[s1] &, Slot[s2] &, Slot[s3] &}]]`.

Comment: haha...well done, thanks!